# WooCommerce purchases are very slow

Tags: wordpress, performance, woocommerce, action-scheduler

It is taking 15 seconds or so from the time the user submits their order for purchase, till they receive the thank you page on my WooCommerce site.

WooCommerce 6.0.0 and Wordpress 5.8.3

The other pages on the site load at an acceptable speed, it is only when the user submits the actual order for purchase that I get the lag.

I am printing to the debug.log and am seeing that there is a 10 second delay between when the order status changed to completed: (woocommerce_order_status_changed hook) and when the thank you page hook is triggered (woocommerce_thankyou hook).

Can someone tell me what happens in between these 2 events or how to fix this?

Note that the lag is happening AFTER the payment has happened so it is not the payment processor.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to leave this here in case it helps someone else.

I have just discovered that this particular lag was caused by Jetpack. As soon as I disabled it, it shaved 10 seconds off of the checkout time. Other pages also sped up.

It still takes about 6 seconds for the whole process but that is for a different post.

Answer (score 1):

Completing all this work probably depends on the action scheduler.

WooCommerce makes extensive use of a scheduling technology, packaged as a WordPress plugin, called [Action Scheduler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/action-scheduler/). Its documentation has sections on running the Action Scheduler on busy WC sites.  There's all kinds of tweaks you can make to increase throughput and decrease wait time.

You haven't told us enough about your situation to make it helpful to offer more advice than that.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I just discovered that it was Jetpack causing a 10 second delay.